# How to detect when a character is walking on an item in Java?

Tags: java, collision-detection

To detect if a character is on an item on the floor, I can check every item on the map and do a collision check, and repeat the process every iteration.

Is there another way to do it, without checking *every* item?

I'm using Java, maybe the language offers a smart way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

A common way to do this is to divide the game world into tiles (which is something you may want to do for other reasons too) and have each tile store a list of the items in it.  That way, you only have to check the items that are in the same tile as the character (or possibly in an adjacent tile, if the items and/or the character can overlap several tiles).

If you have a large world with items scattered sparsely in it, you may also try fancier spatial subdivision techniques like [quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).  In any case, the principle is the same: divide the world into chunks, assign each item or character into a chunk based on their location, and only check for collisions between things in the same or in adjacent chunks.